# Parsing a GTF Gene File

Tags: python, parsing, command-line

I have a GTF file of genes that I trying to parse, so that the 'gene_id,' 'gene_type,' 'gene_status,' 'gene_name,' and level are all in separate columns.

Thus for my original file:

```
chr1 |  ENSEMBL gene|   17369|  17436|  .   -   .   |gene_id "ENSG00000278267.1"; gene_type "miRNA"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "MIR6859-1"; level 3;
chr1 |  ENSEMBL gene|   30366|  30503|  .   +   .   |gene_id "ENSG00000274890.1"; gene_type "miRNA"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "MIR1302-2"; level 3;
chr1 |  ENSEMBL gene|   157784| 157887| .   -   .   |gene_id "ENSG00000222623.1"; gene_type "snRNA"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "RNU6-1100P"; level 3;
chr1 |  ENSEMBL gene|   187891| 187958| .   -   .   |gene_id "ENSG00000273874.1"; gene_type "miRNA"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "MIR6859-2"; level 3;
```

I would like it appear like this, with 'gene_id,' 'gene_type,' 'gene_status,' 'gene_name,' and level all being in SEPARATE columns:

```
 chr1   |ENSEMBL    |gene|  17369|  |17436  |.  -   .   |gene_id "ENSG00000278267.1"   |gene_type "miRNA"   |gene_status "KNOWN"   |gene_name "MIR6859-1"   |level 3
 chr1   |ENSEMBL    |gene|  30366|  30503   |.  +   .   |gene_id "ENSG00000274890.1"   |gene_type "miRNA"   |gene_status "KNOWN"   |gene_name "MIR1302-2"   |level 3 
 chr1   |ENSEMBL    |gene|  157784| 157887  |.  -   .   |gene_id "ENSG00000222623.1"   |gene_type "snRNA"   |gene_status "KNOWN"   |gene_name "RNU6-1100P"  |level 3  
 chr1   |ENSEMBL    |gene|  187891| 187958  |.  -   .   |gene_id "ENSG00000273874.1"   |gene_type "miRNA"   |gene_status "KNOWN"   |gene_name "MIR6859-2"   |level 3
```

I have tried to parse it using gffutils, using the basic code they provide:

```
import gffutils


db = gffutils.create_db("sRNA.gene.gtf", dbfn='sRNA.gene.gtf.db')

print(list(db.featuretypes()))

# Here's how to write genes out to file
with open('sRNA.gene.gtf', 'w') as fout:
  for gene in db.features_of_type('gene'):
    fout.write(str(gene) + '\n')
```

However, I recieve an 'ImportError: cannot import name 'feature:'

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-4dd7cd5c7e24> in <module>()
      2 
      3 
----> 4 db = gffutils.create_db("sRNA.gene.gtf", dbfn='sRNA.gene.gtf.db')
      5 
      6 #db = gffutils.FeatureDB('sRNA.gene.gtf.db')
```

I am not sure what is going wrong here, and now am considering trying to just parse it using the command line. Could anyone please offer some suggestions on the best way to parse GTF files?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please edit your question to include your required output, given your sample input. Good luck.

Comment: Added the changes, thanks!

Comment: hard to see the difference in your input and output. Can you switch to using `|` chars between columns? Are  you then loading this into excel Or similar? Good luck.

Comment: In the original, after 'gene_id' it is all grouped together in one line, I want the variables to all come into different columns by their identifiers.

Comment: What I see is that the `;` chars are removed. Is that enough? `sed 's/;/ /g' file > outFile` will do that. Otherwise, need to know if there is a character that is used to delimit fields. i.e. tab separated? Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, would that still make the values callable i.e. by 'gene_name' etc? I was thinking to maybe put it in a dictionary? What do you think?

Comment: the `sed` solution will clean the data up (per your comment "now am considering trying to just parse it using the command line"). But it seems you have extended your question when you say "I was thinking to maybe put it in a dictionary?" . Now I'm not clear about what is your goal: do you want clean data, or do you have something else to do? Shouldn't that "something else" be in your question? ...I can't be much help with `python` especially without understanding what your ultimate goal is. Finally, I'm a little surprised at the lack of response from the `python` users.  Sorry, but Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help! Well, the ultimate goal is have each line so that I can call out the data by the gene id, gene name etc. I want to use this for a plot later, so all I really need is for the columns to be separate - hence perhaps the dictionary isnt needed! Could you just perhaps help with the sed syntax? I tried what you wrote, but it only removed the first ';' and left the rest. Thanks again!

Comment: hm.. `sed 's/;/ /g' file` should **g**lobally **s**ubstitute all ';' with spaces, are you sure you included the 'g'? Else, if this data has been touched by windows processing, including ftp client, wordpad, etc, then run `dos2unix file` and then run the `sed` (all in a Linux like environment). Good luck.

Comment: Tried again, worked a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You want to change multiple delimiters in a GTF file to a single tab delimiter. Once you've done that the file is no longer a GTF file.

The following code will get the content of the GTF file into a text file

```
import gffutils
try:
    db = gffutils.create_db("sample.gtf", dbfn='sample.db')
except:
    pass
db = gffutils.FeatureDB('sample.db', keep_order=True)
with open('sample.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in db.all_features():
        line = str(line)
        line = line.split(";") #make your parsing changes here
        fout.write(str(line) + '\n')
```

Note that you can only use the `create_db()` method once. That's why I've commented it out.

**EDIT**

Added try statement

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but get the error "DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database"

Comment: @espop23 You might need to uncomment the second line of my code and rename `sample.gtf` to `sRNA.gene.gtf`

Comment: Thanks, it then says "OperationalError: table features already exists" though

Comment: @espop23 Ok, now put the comment sign back in front of the second line of code and try again.

Comment: I have tried the changes, however, it comes out like this: '['chr1\tHAVANA\tgene\t29554\t31109\t.\t+\t.\tgene_id "ENSG00000243485.3"', ' gene_type "lincRNA"', ' gene_status "KNOWN"', ' gene_name "RP11-34P13.3"', ' level "2"', ' tag "ncRNA_host"', ' havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000959.2"', '']'

Comment: I would like the first part, with chr1, tHAVANA etc to be separated by whitespace, so all parts (, and \) are split with whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [pyranges](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/pyranges) library to parse gtf/gff, you will then get each entry in the attribute column as a single column.

Install instructions:

```
# pip install pyranges
# or 
# conda install -c bioconda pyranges
```

Example file:

```
# !head ensembl.gtf
# #!genome-build GRCh38.p10
# #!genome-version GRCh38
# #!genome-date 2013-12
# #!genome-build-accession NCBI:GCA_000001405.25
# #!genebuild-last-updated 2017-06
# 1       havana  gene    11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972"; gene_version "5"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; gene_source "havana"; gene_biotype "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene";
# 1       havana  transcript      11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972"; gene_version "5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328"; transcript_version "2"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; gene_source "havana"; gene_biotype "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-202"; transcript_source "havana"; transcript_biotype "processed_transcript"; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "1";
# 1       havana  exon    11869   12227   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972"; gene_version "5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328"; transcript_version "2"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; gene_source "havana"; gene_biotype "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-202"; transcript_source "havana"; transcript_biotype "processed_transcript"; exon_id "ENSE00002234944"; exon_version "1"; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "1";
# 1       havana  exon    12613   12721   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972"; gene_version "5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328"; transcript_version "2"; exon_number "2"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; gene_source "havana"; gene_biotype "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-202"; transcript_source "havana"; transcript_biotype "processed_transcript"; exon_id "ENSE00003582793"; exon_version "1"; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "1";
# 1       havana  exon    13221   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972"; gene_version "5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328"; transcript_version "2"; exon_number "3"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; gene_source "havana"; gene_biotype "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-202"; transcript_source "havana"; transcript_biotype "processed_transcript"; exon_id "ENSE00002312635"; exon_version "1"; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "1";
```

Using pyranges:

```
import pyranges as pr

# as PyRanges-object
gr = pr.read_gtf("ensembl.gtf")
# +--------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------------+-------+
# | Chromosome   | Source     | Feature      | Start     | End       | Score      | Strand       | Frame      | gene_id         | gene_version   | gene_name   | gene_source    | gene_biotype                       | transcript_id   | transcript_version   | +13   |
# | (category)   | (object)   | (category)   | (int32)   | (int32)   | (object)   | (category)   | (object)   | (object)        | (object)       | (object)    | (object)       | (object)                           | (object)        | (object)             | ...   |
# |--------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------------+-------|
# | 1            | havana     | gene         | 11869     | 14409     | .          | +            | .          | ENSG00000223972 | 5              | DDX11L1     | havana         | transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene | nan             | nan                  | ...   |
# | 1            | havana     | transcript   | 11869     | 14409     | .          | +            | .          | ENSG00000223972 | 5              | DDX11L1     | havana         | transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene | ENST00000456328 | 2                    | ...   |
# | 1            | havana     | exon         | 11869     | 12227     | .          | +            | .          | ENSG00000223972 | 5              | DDX11L1     | havana         | transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene | ENST00000456328 | 2                    | ...   |
# | 1            | havana     | exon         | 12613     | 12721     | .          | +            | .          | ENSG00000223972 | 5              | DDX11L1     | havana         | transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene | ENST00000456328 | 2                    | ...   |
# | ...          | ...        | ...          | ...       | ...       | ...        | ...          | ...        | ...             | ...            | ...         | ...            | ...                                | ...             | ...                  | ...   |
# | 1            | ensembl    | transcript   | 120725    | 133723    | .          | -            | .          | ENSG00000238009 | 6              | AL627309.1  | ensembl_havana | lincRNA                            | ENST00000610542 | 1                    | ...   |
# | 1            | ensembl    | exon         | 133374    | 133723    | .          | -            | .          | ENSG00000238009 | 6              | AL627309.1  | ensembl_havana | lincRNA                            | ENST00000610542 | 1                    | ...   |
# | 1            | ensembl    | exon         | 129055    | 129223    | .          | -            | .          | ENSG00000238009 | 6              | AL627309.1  | ensembl_havana | lincRNA                            | ENST00000610542 | 1                    | ...   |
# | 1            | ensembl    | exon         | 120874    | 120932    | .          | -            | .          | ENSG00000238009 | 6              | AL627309.1  | ensembl_havana | lincRNA                            | ENST00000610542 | 1                    | ...   |
# +--------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------------+-------+
# Stranded PyRanges object has 95 rows and 28 columns from 1 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome and Strand.
# 13 hidden columns: transcript_name, transcript_source, transcript_biotype, tag, transcript_support_level, exon_number, exon_id, exon_version, (assigned, previous, ccds_id, protein_id, protein_version


# as DataFrame
df = gr.df

# Chromosome   Source     Feature   Start     End Score Strand Frame          gene_id gene_version   gene_name  ...    transcript_biotype    tag transcript_support_level exon_number          exon_id exon_version (assigned previous ccds_id protein_id protein_version
# 0           1   havana        gene   11869   14409     .      +     .  ENSG00000223972            5     DDX11L1  ...                   NaN    NaN                      NaN         NaN              NaN          NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN        NaN             NaN
# 1           1   havana  transcript   11869   14409     .      +     .  ENSG00000223972            5     DDX11L1  ...  processed_transcript  basic                        1         NaN              NaN          NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN        NaN             NaN
# 2           1   havana        exon   11869   12227     .      +     .  ENSG00000223972            5     DDX11L1  ...  processed_transcript  basic                        1           1  ENSE00002234944            1       NaN      NaN     NaN        NaN             NaN
# 3           1   havana        exon   12613   12721     .      +     .  ENSG00000223972            5     DDX11L1  ...  processed_transcript  basic                        1           2  ENSE00003582793            1       NaN      NaN     NaN        NaN             NaN
# 4           1   havana        exon   13221   14409     .      +     .  ENSG00000223972            5     DDX11L1  ...  processed_transcript  basic                        1           3  ENSE00002312635            1       NaN      NaN     NaN        NaN             NaN
# ..        ...      ...         ...     ...     ...   ...    ...   ...              ...          ...         ...  ...                   ...    ...                      ...         ...              ...          ...       ...      ...     ...        ...             ...
# 90          1   havana        exon  110953  111357     .      -     .  ENSG00000238009            6  AL627309.1  ...               lincRNA    NaN                        5           3  ENSE00001879696            1       NaN      NaN     NaN        NaN             NaN
# 91          1  ensembl  transcript  120725  133723     .      -     .  ENSG00000238009            6  AL627309.1  ...               lincRNA  basic                        5         NaN              NaN          NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN        NaN             NaN
# 92          1  ensembl        exon  133374  133723     .      -     .  ENSG00000238009            6  AL627309.1  ...               lincRNA  basic                        5           1  ENSE00003748456            1       NaN      NaN     NaN        NaN             NaN
# 93          1  ensembl        exon  129055  129223     .      -     .  ENSG00000238009            6  AL627309.1  ...               lincRNA  basic                        5           2  ENSE00003734824            1       NaN      NaN     NaN        NaN             NaN
# 94          1  ensembl        exon  120874  120932     .      -     .  ENSG00000238009            6  AL627309.1  ...               lincRNA  basic                        5           3  ENSE00003740919            1       NaN      NaN     NaN        NaN             NaN
# 
# [95 rows x 28 columns]
```